# How to set a variable like in this way?

Tags: perl, variables, prefix

I've a variables with prefixes. Can I set a variable in way like this?

`my ${"a","b"}{"b"} = "c"; print $bb; // Prints "c".`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the variables entries in a hash:

```
my %variables;
$variables{$_ . 'b'} = 'c' for (qw(a b));
print $variables{bb}; # prints c
```

The benefit of this is that you can use arbitrary strings as keys, including ones that you generate through string operations (like in the example above). Just be cautious when doing this, as it can overcomplicate the logic of your program. [This posting](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) provides some good insight on what can go wrong with using varying variable names.

Comment: also: `my %var = map { $_ . 'b' => 'c' } qw (a b c);`